# Parameter checks in bash not testing correctly

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

I've been scratching my head about this for a while... I'm trying to get my code to react like:

```
If no parameters, go to menu
If more OR less than 4 parameters, call error and go to menu
If exactly 4 parameters, write to file and exit
```

I can't get this to work in any way, and if you can help that would be majorly appreciated!

```
username=$1
firstname=$2
surname=$3
password=$4

    if test "$#" = 0; then
    {
    menu 
    }
    elif test "$#" = 4; then
    {
   echo Error
    sleep 2
    menu
    }
    else {
     echo Done
     echo "$firstname" "$surname" >> "$username".log
    echo "$password" >> "$username".log
    curdate=$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    echo "$curdate" >> "$username".log
    sleep 2
    clear
    exit
    }
    fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, numeric comparisons are not done with `=` but are done with `-eq` and its ilk. (`=` is for string comparison.)

So you want something like this. I'm going to replace your `test` with the much more common `[` notation.

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] ; then
{
    menu 
}
elif [ "$#" -eq 4 ] ; then
...
```

Mort